How to delete app keychain login info?
How can I stop an app from tracking my login information even after I completely uninstall and reinstall it? I suspect the app is using keychain for this purpose. I was able to remove the keychain entries from my Mac, but I'm unsure how to delete the keychain entries on my phone. Is there a solution for this?

Do these answer your question? Deleting an app’s data from the iOS Keychain, or resetting the Keychain entirely or How can I remove keychain data from iOS?

If you are sure the keychain contains this, we will close this as an exact duplicate of existing questions. If you are not so sure how your specific app is working, please edit details on your specific problem and we can reopen this if it’s not actually the general keychain reset question you asked initially. Please edit those details so we can review this and vote to reopen in that case.
